# Coldfusion WSS4J java soap signer certificate gone after first signing

Tags: java, web-services, soap, coldfusion, wss4j

I have been trying to troubleshoot this issue for a few months now. I worked out a few problems with my java object by upgrading to the latest version of WSS4J and all of my test cases work using the Coldfusion JRE for testing inside of Eclipse. When I export the jar and add it to the classpath in Coldfusion and reset Coldfusion, the object will sign the SOAP request the first time and will start throwing errors after that. It will always sign the first request. I have tried JavaLoader also to try and load it from the jar every time but that does not work either.

Here is the Coldfusion code:

```
<cfset Soap = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'> <soap:Body> <test1></test1> </soap:Body> </soap:Envelope>">

<cfloop from="1" to="5" index="i">
    <cfset Signer = CreateObject("java","com.soapsigner.SoapSigner").init(Soap)>
    <cfdump var="#Signer.getLastError()#">
    <cfdump var="#Signer.getXML()#">
    <br  /><br /><br />
</cfloop>

<cfabort>
```

Here is the Java code using `WSS4J 2.0.1`

```
package com.soapsigner;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout;
import org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.Crypto;
import org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.Merlin;
import org.apache.wss4j.dom.WSConstants;
import org.apache.wss4j.dom.message.WSSecHeader;
import org.apache.wss4j.dom.message.WSSecSignature;
import org.apache.wss4j.dom.message.WSSecTimestamp;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class SoapSigner {
    private Crypto crypto;
    private WSSecSignature sig;
    private WSSecTimestamp time;
    private WSSecHeader header; 
    private String alias;
    private String password;
    private String keyFile;
    private String keyFileType;
    private Document signedDoc;
    private String lastError;
    {
        Logger rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger();
        rootLogger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        rootLogger.addAppender(new ConsoleAppender(
                   new PatternLayout("%-6r [%p] %c - %m%n")));
    }
    static { org.apache.xml.security.Init.init(); }

    //constructor
    public SoapSigner(String XML){
        try {           
            alias = "myalias";
            password = "mypassword";
            keyFile = "/keystore/keystore.pkcs";
            keyFileType = "pkcs12";
            sig = new WSSecSignature(); 
            time = new WSSecTimestamp();
            header = new WSSecHeader();
            signedDoc = null;
            lastError = "";         

            Merlin merlin = new Merlin(getCryptoProperties(), null, null);
            crypto = merlin;            

            signDocument(xmlToDoc(XML));
            /*testing
            System.out.println(getXML());
            System.out.println(getLastError());
            */
        } catch (Exception e) {
            setLastError(e);
        }
    }

    //properties
    public Properties getCryptoProperties(){
        Properties cryptoProperties = new Properties();
        cryptoProperties.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias", alias);       
        cryptoProperties.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password", password);
        cryptoProperties.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type", keyFileType);
        cryptoProperties.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file", keyFile);        
        return cryptoProperties;        
    }

    //sign the document
    public void signDocument(Document doc){             
        try {   
            header.setMustUnderstand(true);
            sig.setSignatureAlgorithm(WSConstants.C14N_EXCL_OMIT_COMMENTS);
            sig.setSignatureAlgorithm(WSConstants.RSA);
            sig.setUserInfo(alias, password);
            sig.setKeyIdentifierType(WSConstants.BST_DIRECT_REFERENCE); 
            header.insertSecurityHeader(doc);
            sig.build(doc, crypto, header);
            time.build(doc, header);
            signedDoc = doc;
        } catch (Exception e) {         
            setLastError(e);
        }           
    }

    //get the signed document
    public Document getDocument(){      
        return signedDoc;       
    }

    //get the signed xml
    public String getXML(){
        return getStringFromDoc(getDocument()).trim();
    }

    //get last error
    public String getLastError(){
        return lastError;
    }

    //set last error
    private void setLastError(Throwable e){
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
        lastError += "     NEXT ERROR     "+sw.toString();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

    //document to string
    public String getStringFromDoc(Document doc){
        try
        {
           DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
           StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
           StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
           TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
           Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
           transformer.transform(domSource, result);
           writer.flush();
           return writer.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
           setLastError(e);
           return null;
        }
    }

    //string to document
    public Document xmlToDoc(String XML){   
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder db;     
            db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();      
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(XML));
            Document doc = db.parse(is);
        return doc;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            setLastError(e);
            return null;
        }       
    }

    //main
    public static void main(String[] args){
        /*testing, these test cases work
        String XML1 = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'> <soap:Body> <test1></test1> </soap:Body> </soap:Envelope>";  
        String XML2 = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'> <soap:Body> <test2></test2> </soap:Body> </soap:Envelope>";  
        new SoapSigner(XML1);       
        new SoapSigner(XML2);      
        */
    }
}
```

The error I get on the second loop:

```
org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: No message with ID "noUserCertsFound" found in resource bundle "org/apache/xml/security/resource/xmlsecurity" at
org.apache.wss4j.dom.message.WSSecSignature.getSigningCerts(WSSecSignature.java:823) at
org.apache.wss4j.dom.message.WSSecSignature.prepare(WSSecSignature.java:167) at 
org.apache.wss4j.dom.message.WSSecSignature.build(WSSecSignature.java:375) at    
com.soapsigner.SoapSigner.signDocument(SoapSigner.java:91) at com.soapsigner.SoapSigner.<init>(SoapSigner.java:63) at 
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at 
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) at
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) at 
coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxy.CreateObject(JavaProxy.java:166) at 
coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxy.invoke(JavaProxy.java:80) at
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2483) at 
cfindex2ecfm836201788.runPage(C:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot\testsite\index.cfm:4) at
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:246) at    
coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.handlePageInvoke(IncludeTag.java:734) at
coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:570) at 
coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65) at
coldfusion.filter.IpFilter.invoke(IpFilter.java:45) at 
coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:487) at 
coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:42) at
coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40) at
coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:141) at 
coldfusion.filter.LicenseFilter.invoke(LicenseFilter.java:30) at
coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94) at
coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke
(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28) at
coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38) at 
coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:58) at
coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38) at 
coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22) at
coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62) at 
coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:219) at 
coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89) at   
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) at    
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at   
coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter
(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42) at 
coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at    
coldfusion.inspect.weinre.MobileDeviceDomInspectionFilter.doFilter
(MobileDeviceDomInspectionFilter.java:121) at   
coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke
(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke
(StandardContextValve.java:122) at 
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke
(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke
(StandardHostValve.java:170) at 
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) at
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:422) at 
org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:198) at 
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process
(AbstractProtocol.java:607) at 
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at 
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Depending on how I load the jars I get this error also:

```
org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: No certificates for user 1 were found for signature
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.message.WSSecSignature.getSigningCerts(WSSecSignature.java:823)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.message.WSSecSignature.prepare(WSSecSignature.java:167)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.message.WSSecSignature.build(WSSecSignature.java:375)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at coldfusion.runtime.StructBean.invoke(StructBean.java:508)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2553)
    at cfindex2ecfm836201788.runPage(C:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot\testsite\index.cfm:36)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:246)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.handlePageInvoke(IncludeTag.java:734)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:570)
    at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)
    at coldfusion.filter.IpFilter.invoke(IpFilter.java:45)
    at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:487)
    at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:141)
    at coldfusion.filter.LicenseFilter.invoke(LicenseFilter.java:30)
    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:58)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:219)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at coldfusion.inspect.weinre.MobileDeviceDomInspectionFilter.doFilter(MobileDeviceDomInspectionFilter.java:121)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:422)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

After changing `org.apache.xml.security.Init` these are the errors after the first loop:

```
org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: No certificates for user 1 were found for signature at
org.apache.wss4j.dom.message.WSSecSignature.getSigningCerts(WSSecSignature.java:823) at
org.apache.wss4j.dom.message.WSSecSignature.prepare(WSSecSignature.java:167) at
org.apache.wss4j.dom.message.WSSecSignature.build(WSSecSignature.java:375) at
com.soapsigner.SoapSigner.signDocument(SoapSigner.java:93) at com.soapsigner.SoapSigner.<init>(SoapSigner.java:65) at
 sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) at
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) at
coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxy.CreateObject(JavaProxy.java:166) at
coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxy.invoke(JavaProxy.java:80) at 
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2483) at
cfindex2ecfm836201788.runPage(C:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot\testsite\index.cfm:60) at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:246) at
coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.handlePageInvoke(IncludeTag.java:734) at
coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:570) at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65) at
 coldfusion.filter.IpFilter.invoke(IpFilter.java:45) at
 coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:487) at
 coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:42) at
 coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40) at
 coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:141) at
 coldfusion.filter.LicenseFilter.invoke(LicenseFilter.java:30) at 
 coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94) at
    coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28) at 
coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38) at
coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:58) at
coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38) at 
coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22) at
coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62) at 
coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:219) at 
coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89) at        
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) at     
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at 
coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter
(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42) at 
coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46) at    
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at    
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at 
coldfusion.inspect.weinre.MobileDeviceDomInspectionFilter.doFilter
(MobileDeviceDomInspectionFilter.java:121) at 
coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter
(BootstrapFilter.java:46) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) at
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) at
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) at 
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98) at
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) at
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:422) at 
 org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:198) at 
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607) at 
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at
 java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

static { org.apache.xml.security.Init.init(); }

try:

static { org.apache.wss4j.dom.WSSConfig.init(); }

Comment: thanks for the help. I did change those and it still works in Eclipse but does the same thing in Coldfusion. I updated my original message with the newest error because it is different than the previous ones.

Comment: Is there any way to create a test-case that I can use to reproduce the problem? If so then create a new WSS4J JIRA + attach it there. Failing that, you could try with the latest WSS4J 2.0.2-SNAPSHOT code (or wait til 2.0.2 is out next week or so) + test with that, to see if it has been fixed.

Comment: I tried to find the 2.0.2 download but can't seem to find it. Do you have a link for it? I can try to test that out. I could create a test case over on your site, but I think the issue might be more related to how Coldfusion handles the Jars. I use the JRE that Coldfusion runs in Eclipse and it works fine. I run the Soap Signer in Coldfusion and it fails. If I created a test case over there with the Jar files and Coldfusion files, would someone be able to test it on a Coldfusion server?

Comment: 2.0.2 is not released yet. You can download the SNAPSHOT jars here: http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/wss4j/ - I don't have access to a Coldfusion server.